# Mean value theorem problem (I think)

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$.

If $f'(x)$ does not equal $1$ for any $x \in (0,1)$, show that there is exactly one $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c) = c$.

I don't understand.  If $f'(x)$ can't equal 1, how can $f(c)=c$?

The only thing I can think to do is use the mean value theorem.

Comment: Use the mean value theorem to show the existence of a fixed point ($f(c) = c$), and use the condition on $f'$ to show it's unique.

Answer (score 1):

Use the intermediate value theorem on $g(x) = f(x) - x$ to establish the existence of $c$.  Use the mean value theorem to show it is unique.

Comment: Doesn't the IVT only apply if f(a)<0<f(b)?

Comment: @user111930 That is the intermediate value theorem, not the **mean** value theorem.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff yes, that's what I was asking since the answer given by Stephen suggested using the intermediate value theorem first.

Comment: @user111930 Oh, no. The IVT says that $f([a,b])$ is an interval for $f$ continuous. That's all.

Comment: I added details on how to use the IVT.

Comment: But I also upvoted two other answers that explain with more details.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** consider the function $g(x) = f(x) - x$.  What can we say about $g(0)$ and $g(1)$?  What does Rolle's theorem tell us if $g(x)$ has two zeros?

Answer (score 1):

The graph of $f$ fits in $[0,1]^2$. $(0,f(0))$ lines on the  left hand side and $(1,f(1))$ lines on the right hand side. So the line joining $(0,f(0))$ and $(1,f(1))$ **must** cross the line ${(x,x)}_{x \in [0,1]}$ (by the intermediate value theorem). This gives existence.

For uniqueness, suppose two points lie on the line, that is $f(a) = a$ and $f(b) = b$ for some $a < b$. Then the mean value theorem shows that for some $\xi \in (a,b)$ we must have $f'(\xi) = 1$, which is a contradiction. Hence at most one point lines on the line.

Answer (score 0):

Well precisely... what you want to do is mean value theorem. First though, you ask hwo can $f(c) = c$. Well let $f'(x) = 3x^2+2$ and $f(x) = x^3 + 2x$. It is clear that $f(0) = 0$, but $f'(x)\geq 2$.

Define the auxiliary function $g(x) = f(x) - x$.  Then, $g'(x) = f'(x) - 1$. Suppose $g(a)=g(b)$. Then, $0 \equiv g(b)-g(a) = g'(\xi)\cdot (b-a)$. But $g'(\xi) \neq 0$. Hence, $a=b$ and any solution is a unique solution $c$ such that $f(c) = c$. It suffices to show by the Intermediate Value Theorem that some solution exists namely $f(1)-1 \leq 0 \leq f(0) - 0$.